# converting projections using dotspatial or proj4

Tags: proj, sharpmap, dotspatial

how can i convert projections using either dotspatial or proj4?
i am making a program using sharpmap and dotspatial in VB.net
have to convert a EPSG 4030 into a Lambert conformal conic projection and back to WGS84 on the fly
also can i convert a system on the fly using a WKT?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your question whether you know the proj4 string for the projection you want to convert into. DotSpatial has some built-in projections under DotSpatial.Projections.KnownCoordinateSystems, but I can't locate Lambert.

If you just want to know how to use DotSpatial, you can use code like this, passing in the proj4 strings (sorry it's in C#, but it should be easy to translate):

```
public override ReprojectPoint(ref Point[] point, string sourceProjection, string destinationProjection)
{
    double[] pntXY = new double[point.Length * 2];
    double[] pntZ = new double[point.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < point.Length; i++)
    {
        pntXY[i*2] = point[i].x;
        pntXY[i*2+1] = point[i].y;

        pntZ[i] = 1;
    }

    ProjectionInfo src = new ProjectionInfo(sourceProjection),
                dst = new ProjectionInfo(destinationProjection);


    Reproject.ReprojectPoints(pntXY, pntZ, src, dst, 0, point.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < point.Length; i++)
    {
        point[i].x = pntXY[i*2];
        point[i].y = pntXY[i*2+1];
    }
}

public struct Point
{
    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double x;
    public double y;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "POINT(" + x.ToString() + " " + y.ToString() + ")";
    }
}
```

I don't think there's any support for reprojecting WKT on-the-fly in DotSpatial - you'd need to write some code to parse it.